# How to get values to ArrayList of Class, from jsp page using jstl tag?

Tags: spring, jsp

This is my first VO class member variable:

```
private List<ProgramToStudyMap> programToStudyMaps;
```

And here is ProgramToStudyMap Class:

```
public class ProgramToStudyMap {

    private Long studyId;
    private List<Long> programId;

}
```

And my jsp code is,

```
<form:checkbox path="programToStudyMaps[0].studyId" />
```

But it's giving error like,

```
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'programToStudyMaps[0]' of bean class [java.util.ArrayList]: Bean property 'programToStudyMaps[0]' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
```

This is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = RequestMap.MAINTENANCE_STUDY_PROGRAMS, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody JsonResponse maintananceStudyProgramsSave(@ModelAttribute ProgramToStudyVo programToStudyVo) {
        JsonResponse jsonResponse = new JsonResponse();
        try {
            System.out.println("---------- "+programToStudyVo.getProgramToStudyMaps().get(0).getStudyId());
            System.out.println("---------- "+programToStudyVo.getProgramToStudyMaps().get(0).getProgramId());
            System.out.println("------------- "+programToStudyVo.getProgramToStudyMaps().get(1).getStudyId());
            System.out.println("------------- "+programToStudyVo.getProgramToStudyMaps().get(1).getProgramId());
            jsonResponse.setStatus(RhoConstants.JSON_SUCCESS);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }
        return jsonResponse;
    }
```

How can I resolve this.?

Comment: How do you set the `attribute` in the `request` , it will be more appropriate if you show your `Controller` class. And i dont see any `jstl` code , so removing the tag

Comment: request is processing through the command name: like this. <form:form action="MaintenanceStudyPrograms" method="post" commandName="programToStudyVo"> and in my controller taking it as modelattribute : @ModelAttribute ProgramToStudyVo programToStudyVo

Comment: please confirm that you are using `spring form` tld. Have you checked whether you have added the attribute in your controller to print it in the `jsp`

Comment: Yes I have spring form in my jsp
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
Im checking it in my controller with
System.out.println("---------- "+programToStudyVo.getProgramToStudyMaps().get(0).getStudyId());

Comment: Please add the controller code wrt to your question atleast to help you . you can edit your own question too

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are sending the `json` response from the server and trying to display the results using `spring:form` tags , which cant be done as though.

You can do a alternative method if you want to end up with `json`, handle the response using `javascript`and populate the checkbox values

Else if you wish to go with `spring:form`  you need to add the values to the `Model` using `model.addAttribute()` method and display it using `path` property
Also remember path `property` should match the property names of your model class.

IMHO , take this [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_mvc_form_handling_example.htm) to have some idea before you start with.